# How to ask for response in an official letter?

Tags: letter

I am writing an official letter along with my resume to the president of a sports federation so that I can enroll in the federation. When my letter concludes, how can I officially say *Please reply to this letter*?

> Dear Sir
>   Respectfully, I am sending you my championship and coaching resume and documents. I would appreciate it if you minded looking into the dispatched documents. 
>   It would be my pleasure to contribute, with my attendance, to the qualitative level of your national team in terms of securing various world championships. Your answer is greatly appreciated in advance.

Comment: You cannot. That would be impolite. If the president is the correct person to ask for admission (which I doubt), he will reply, because then it is part of his duties. If the president shouldn't have to deal with inquiries such as yours, because those letters should be addressed to the admissions bureau, then asking him to reply to a matter he shouldn't have to deal with in the first place is doubly audacious.

Answer (score 2):

I would not consider adding any sentence requesting a response. Instead, saying "I would look forward to the opportunity to discuss your team" or something of that nature. That, as an example, highlights that you would look forward to further conversation initiated on their end.